Linear algebra with matrices using Eigen
I am developing an application that reads in a 3x3 rotation matrix from 3D Slicer and computes a direction vector by multiplying with a "magic" vector (0,0,1). This magic vector was chosen because the initial non-rotated vector in Slicer points straight down. It works, and I can display the vectors in my application.
Now I want to do the opposite. I want to allow the user to rotate the vector, then output a 3x3 rotation matrix that can be imported by Slicer.
I have looked at:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html
Where they solve Ax=b for x given A and b. Is it possible to solve for A given x and b? In this case, x would by my "magic" vector (0,0,1) and b would be the direction vector of my object.
I think it would be possible to get the rotation matrix using Euler angles, but it seems confusing.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question sounds more math-related than programming related.   Perhaps ask in Maths Stack Exchange?

There are ways to find the rotation.  The one that's the easiest for me to use is a quaternion.  Cross product gives the axis, dot product gives the angle.  Make the quaternion, then use toRotationMatrix() to get the 3x3 matrix.

If I understand you correctly, you want roughly this:

Represent the rotation from one vector (the magic vector) to the new vector. We can use Quaternion::FromTwoVectors for this


Returns a quaternion representing a rotation between the two arbitrary vectors a and b. In other words, the built rotation represent a rotation sending the line of direction a to the line of direction b, both lines passing through the origin


Transform that to a rotation matrix: QuaternionBase::toRotationMatrix

#include <Eigen/Geometry>

Eigen::Vector3d magic = Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ();
Eigen::Vector3d direction {1., 2., 3.};
Eigen::Matrix3d rotation =
    Eigen::Quaterniond::FromTwoVectors(magic, direction).toRotationMatrix();

